# The base memory can still access after deleting the derived class

Tags: c++, destructor, derived-class

There is no explicit destructor in base class. Then, I delete the derived class with derived pointer. After that, if I access the member of the derived class, the crash happened. However, if I access the base member, the program still ok. Why?

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
protected:
    virtual ~Base() {} // if I remove the destructor, then the program still run ok even if I remove the derived class.
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived() {}
    void doSomething() override { a_ = true; }
private:
    bool a_;
};

Derived *pD = new Derived();
Base *pB = static_cast<Base*>(pD);
delete pD;

pB->doSomething(); // the program is ok if I remove the destructor in base class
pD->doSomething(); // the program crash no matter the destructor of base class is there or not.
```

Comment: "Undefined behavior" means anything can happen. All bets are off.

Comment: Part of the glory and majesty of C++ is that there are a large number of "undefined behaviors" where the language spec essentially just says "don't do that -- but if you do do that, then whatever happens, happens, and you aren't allowed to complain about it, because you shouldn't have done that in the first place".   Dereferencing a dangling pointer is one such undefined behavior... so, don't do it :)

Answer (score 1):

> if I access the member of derived class, the crash happpend.
>
> if I access the base member, the program still ok. Why?

Because the behaviour of accessing through an invalid pointer is undefined.